# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) After Install Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: mysql, unix, ubuntu-15.04

I have Just setup Ubuntu 15.04 and Install mysql-server with following command

```
>sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

It ask me for password for root user .. I set '123456' as password... it ask me again for confirm password again I type '123456' after installation

I try this command

```
glenn@acer:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: (123456)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

So what is too complex in it ? even when I try re-install and leave that empty that also not working...

Comment: For future remember that `sql-server` tag is for `Microsoft SQL Sever`

Comment: Have you installed or verified mysql-client is available?